# $\mu(X \bigcap [0, r))>0,\mu(X \bigcap [-r, 0))>0$ for all $r >0 $ implies there some non zero $x$ , $x \in X,-x \in X$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given some Lebesgue measurable set $X$ and Lebesgue measure $\mu$

$\mu(X \bigcap [0,  r))>0,\mu(X \bigcap [-r,  0))>0$ for all $r >0 $ implies there some non zero $x$ , $x \in X,-x \in X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Let us define:
$$A:=\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)\bigcup\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}\right)\bigcup \left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5}\right)\bigcup \ldots~,$$
$$B:=\left(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3}\right)\bigcup\left(-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{1}{5}\right)\bigcup \left(-\frac{1}{6},-\frac{1}{7}\right)\bigcup \ldots~,$$ and let $X = A\bigcup B$.

Comment: +1. Nice example!